# How to cancel an Rsync mirror on Ubuntu?

Tags: rsync

I mistakenly synced two folders, one on my Ubuntu 18.04 server and one on a NAS.

I did some research on Google but I couldn't find anything conclusive.

I would like to know how to cancel the mirror synchronization of Rsync.

Comment: Exactly how did you mistakenly sync them (give exact commands)?

Comment: @Organic Marble `sudo rsync -av /var/lib/automysqlbackup/daily/redcap/ username@x.x.x.x:volume1/BackupServer/DAtabase`

Comment: So this is not an ongoing thing, you are asking how to undo something you did?

Comment: Yes, because the destination folder is not the right one

Comment: If you over-wrote files, restore from backup. If you just added a bunch of files you don't want there, manually remove them. In future, use the --dry-run feature of rsync.

Answer (score 1):

> How to cancel an Rsync mirror on Ubuntu?

While the `rsync` operation is in process, it can be interrupted in the usual ways, e.g. using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or `pkill` etc. What has been done thus far, however, cannot be undone.

If you mean something different, note that you cannot "cancel" your mirror. Once the target file system has been updated, it has irreversibly changed. Reverting to a previous state could only be done by restoring a backup.

Comment: So it's impossible to unsynced those folder ?

Comment: Quite clearly so. Restore a backup to restore the folder to a previous state. It is like moving boxes. You can stop one moving more boxes, but the boxes already moved stay.